# Need to replace <p>Are you? [xxxrecipientFirstNamexxx] </p> with <p>Are you? {recipientFirstName} </p>

Tags: java, regex, boundary

Need to replace

Are you? [xxxrecipientFirstNamexxx]

with

Are you? {recipientFirstName}

.
I tried using Boundary Matchers .But result is not as expected .
I tried with below code

```
"<p>Are you? [xxxrecipientFirstNamexxx] </p>".replaceAll("\\b[[xxxrecipientFirstNamexxx]]\\b", "{recipientFirstName}");
```

.Can any one help on this?

Comment: Use REGEX: `\[xxx(.*)xxx\]` and replace it with `{$1}`

Comment: It worked on my system, flawlessly

Comment: Use a non greedy regex `\[xxx(.*?)xxx\]` or you may have problems if there are multiple strings to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use REGEX to find and replace:

Find: `\[xxx(.*)xxx\]`

Replace it with `{$1}`

In python:

```
import re

line = re.sub(
           r"\[xxx(.*)xxx\]", 
           "{$1}", 
           line
       )
```

Comment: OP asks a Java solution, not Python.

Comment: The quesrion is about Java, instead of your code in python you can mention `"<p>Are you? [xxxrecipientFirstNamexxx] </p>"
        .replaceAll("\\[xxx(.*)xxx\\]", "$1")` in Java

Comment: @Toto Does it matter, whether you specify `REGEX` in `python` or `java`?